# Coset of an infinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I am required to describe the cosets of the following subgroups:

$\left<\frac 1 2\right>$ of $\mathbb R^\times$ and $\left<1/2\right>$ of $(\mathbb R,+)$.

I think I was able to define the coset of $(R,+)$ which i noted was $a+\left<\frac 1 2\right>$ where $0\leq a<\frac12$

I am more familiar with cylic groups of addition rather than multiplication, so I am struggling with coset $\left<1/2\right>$ of $\mathbb R^\times$. I know that it contains products of $\frac12$ and $2$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please peruse this tutorial to learn the basics of MathJax for typesetting math on this site:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should be able to show that $\langle\frac12\rangle=\{2^k:k\in\Bbb Z\}.$ Given any $\alpha\in\Bbb R^\times,$ we then have $\langle\frac12\rangle\alpha=\{2^k\alpha:k\in\Bbb Z\}.$ Can you figure out all such cosets?

Comment: Yeah i am aware that ⟨12⟩={2k:k∈ℤ} would the coset be ⟨12⟩α were 0≤α<1?

Comment: Not at all. Remember that $0$ isn't an element of $\Bbb R^\times.$ Also, note that (for example) if $H=\langle\frac12\rangle,$ then $H\cdot\alpha=H\cdot\frac12\alpha$. You'll need to find different intervals. Also, note that just one interval of values for $\alpha$ won't be enough to do the trick, here. (Why not?)

Comment: Do i need multilple intervals in order to satisfy positive and negative values in R?

Comment: Precisely! You'll need one interval to take care of all the positive values, and one to take care of all the negative values.

Comment: Would such intervals be 0<a<1 and -1<a<0 or are the intervals more restricted?

Comment: Those intervals will work, but there will be infinitely-many $\alpha$ in each interval that give the same cosets. Remember, $0$ isn't special in $\Bbb R^\times$ (it isn't even in there), but $1$ *is*. We'll still want to use half-open, half-closed intervals, but it would be better to start at $1$ and $-1$ for those intervals, rather than starting at (and then deleting) $0.$

Comment: Yea i was going to edit the intervals to include 1 and -1 since 0 is not in R*.

Comment: Let me put it another way. Rather than the interval $0\le\alpha<1,$ you should consider the interval $$\left(\frac12\right)^0\ge\alpha>\left(\frac12\right)^1.$$ A similar interval will take care of all the negative numbers without repeats.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;a,b\in\Bbb R^*\;$ and denote $\;N:=\langle\,\frac12\,\rangle\;$ ,then

$$aN=bN\iff ab^{-1}\in N\iff ab^{-1}=\frac1{2^k}\;,\;\;\text{for some}\;k\in\Bbb Z\iff a= 2^{m}b\;,\;\;m\in\Bbb Z$$

For example, we have that

$$3N=6N=\frac34N\neq5N$$

Take now $\;a,b\in\Bbb R\;$ with the same notation as above (though the groups and subgroups are very different!), then

$$a+N=b+N\iff a-b\in N\iff \;\exists\, k\in\Bbb Z\,\,s.t.\,\,a-b=\frac12k\iff a=b+\frac12k$$

For example,

$$\frac56+N=\frac13+N\neq1+N$$